# Quantifier explination: $\forall x(R\to Q(x))\equiv R \to \forall x (Q(x))$

Tags: logic, quantifiers

I don't understand the proof for this problem and couldn't find the answer anywhere.

$$\forall x(R\to Q(x))\equiv R \to \forall x (Q(x))$$

Comment: You don't understand what proof?

Comment: This is just one of those quirks of FOL that must annoy mathematicians. In a math textbook, the domain of discussion would always be made explicit, greatly simplifying problems like this. Hint: Think of your theorem as $\forall x\in U: [R \implies Q(x)]\equiv R \implies \forall x\in U: Q(x)$. In this case, you do not even a have to assume that $U$ is non-empty.

Comment: In Hagen's proof below, instead of "let $x$ be arbitrary", you could suppose that $x\in U$.

Comment: This theorem is the generalization of $\{R \Rightarrow Q_1,~ R \Rightarrow Q_2\} \equiv (R \Rightarrow (Q_1 \land Q_2))$ , which for some logicians is the definition of $\land$.

Answer (score 2):

Think of it first from a concrete approach, in order to get a better feel for what you're looking to prove in the general case.

Example: (Domain of x is all people)

$R:$ It is raining. (Note that R is independent of any x)

$Q(x): x$ takes an umbrella or gets wet.

$\forall x(R \rightarrow Q(x))\tag 1$

$R\rightarrow \forall x(Q(x))\tag 2$

$(1)$ "says" Everyone, if it's raining, takes an umbrella or gets wet.

$(2)$ "says" If it is raining, everyone takes an umbrella or gets wet.

The important thing to note is that $R$, by itself, is a statement, and can, but need not be included in the bounds over which x is quantified.

Hopefully this explanation helps you to understand the general case. @Hagen von Eitzen has already given you the technical details of the proof you may be seeking.

In the future, when you encounter a question which overwhelms upon first site, break it down into smaller pieces. If you are being asked to prove anything about $x$, universally (in a given domain)...get a feel for what it looks like concretely,  in a particular interpretation of the domain of $x$ and predicates used, to try to get a sense of what you are working with.

Answer (score 1):

Assume $\forall x(R\to Q(x))$. We want to prove $R\to \forall x Q(x)$.
So we assume $R$ and attempt to prove $\forall x Q(x)$.
So we let $x$ be arbitrary. For this $x$ we have, by specialization, that $R\to Q(x)$. As $R$, modus ponens gives us $Q(x)$. As $x$ was arbitrary, $\forall x Q(x)$. So we derived $\forall x Q(x)$ based on the hypthesis that $R$ holds. In other words, we have shown $R\to \forall x Q(x)$. This shows the $\implies$ direction of the desired equivalence.

Now assume instead that $R\to \forall x Q(x)$.
We want to prove $\forall x(R\to Q(x))$. 
So let $x$ be arbitrary. 
We want to prove $R\to Q(x)$.
So assume $R$. Then by modus ponens $\forall x Q(x)$.
In particular, $Q(x)$.
Thus we showed $Q(x)$ from $R$, i.e., we showed $R\to Q(x)$.
As $x$ was aribitrary, we showed $\forall x(R\to Q(x))$. This shows the other direction.